# How can I get system display name with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I get system display name of a file, directory, or folder as it would be displayed in a system file browser? For example original CD is named somehow and I want to do little copy protection

Comment: File names are commonly displayed as is.  Name of CD (media) is different from CD name and from your redacted question is not clear to me if you want a file name or the inserted media name of a CD.  On the other hand, if you pretend to protect it checking the CD, I have to say nowadays software is rarely distributed on a CD, are you sure you want to protect it checking the media name for a CD?

Comment: 2jachguate: No need to surprise, CD is enough. For example, I put a CD into CD-ROM. In My Computer window I can see list of partitions like "System (C:), Main (D:), SomeCDtoBeProtected (E:)". See now? I don't know how to call it another way, but this string "SomeCDtoBeProtected" or at least "SomeCDtoBeProtected (E:)" I need. The term "Display name of a file..." I took here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemDisplayName%28java.io.File%29  . Java can make it, can Inno Setup? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup provides no such functions. However, you can easily write your own DLL that investigates the label of the CD drive of the setup program. In Pascal, just do

```
function GetCDLabel: string;
var
  VolumeName: PChar;
  dummy: cardinal;
begin
  GetMem(VolumeName, MAX_PATH * sizeof(char));
  try
    if GetVolumeInformation(PChar('D:\'), VolumeName, MAX_PATH + 1, nil, dummy, dummy, nil, 0) then
      result := VolumeName
    else
      RaiseLastOSError; // or result := 'Invalid';
  finally
    FreeMem(VolumeName);
  end;
end;
```

Inno Setup lets you include DLLs with your setup, and call functions in these DLLs during setup. Of course, your setup must tell the DLL function its filename, so that the DLL function can use the right drive. You cannot just assume it is `D:\`.